# Modular Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, module

I'd like to build a control panel (let's call it "dashboard") for several applications. Each application has a REST-API which will be used by the dashboard. The dashboard should have a module for every managed application.

In Rails I could use [Controller Namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) to achieve something like this. The models and the views could be separated in a similar way. This would lead to the following directory structure:

- controllers/app1/
- models/app1/
- views/app1/
- controllers/app2/
- models/app2/
- views/app2/

But I don't like that. I would rather have something like this, to have the modules better separated:

- modules/app1/controllers
- modules/app1/models
- modules/app1/views
- modules/app2/controllers
- modules/app2/models
- modules/app2/views

Is something like this possible with Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that kind of separation you should investigate using [Rails Engines](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) to organize the components of your application. An engine is a sort of sub-application that's mostly self-contained.